# Customising of system activities of UIActivityViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, ios6, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'd like to use `UIActivityViewController` to share different content via Facebook, Twitter and Mail. But in addition to sharing I need also do some things, for example logging.

1. Is there a possibility to  add custom functionality to system `UIActivities`?
2. If not, is this a proper way to subclass UIActivity to provide share via Facebook, Twitter, Mail?
3. Or may be `UIActivityViewController` is too simplified and I have to use custom view controller for custom purposes?